# Using resources with the same name in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

Is there a way to add multiple resources with the same name to an Xcode project and have 1 of them take priority over the others?

Example:
I added 2 files, both called icon.png, to an Xcode project. They are on different folders in the file system (Folder1/icon.png and Folder2/icon.png) and on different groups in Xcode. Is there a way to tell Xcode to have Folder2/icon.png take priority over Folder1/icon.png? And if only 1 icon.png exists, then use that one.

Thanks.

**EDIT (2010-12-23):**

You can have multiple files with the same name in an Xcode project even if they are not in separate folder references, but they are in separate groups. Once compiled, the app bundle (which will be flat with no folders in it), will only have one copy of the file (icon.png). How do you pick which copy of the file to use?

I was told that you can do this for BlackBerry. It works something like this: The compiler will go down the list of files in the project and start adding them to the app bundle. If it sees a duplicate, it will overwrite it (or not), so the files at the bottom (or at the top) will have higher precedence and will be the final bundle.

Comment: It sounds like this is the wrong solution a problem that I am not sure of.  Why dont you edit the question and we can come up with better solutions to solve your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can better easily be solved by using folders within a resource bundle in your Xcode project.  Take a look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to use folder references? Interface builder doesn't seem to pick up files inside folders that have been added by reference (blue folder icons), even though it works when you type the name manually, i.e. /folder1/mail_icon.png.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a second, since you specifically mentioned icon.png, are you trying to supply different iDevices (iPad, iPhone4, iTouch3...) with different icon images?

If yes, check this out, http://d.pr/W2w0 , Apple has already provided a way for us to finish this task with convenience. All you need to do is following a specific naming convention.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of this. I'm trying to supply different icons for different clients. I have an app that uses a bunch of default icons, but client X wants to use use their own mail_icon.png and client Y wants to do the same. Is there a way to tell Xcode "if there are 2 mail_icon.png files, use the one in this folder" without having to use folder references?

Comment: Well then I've no idea... I'm also interested in the answer. Anybody can help?

Answer (score -1):

What we do if we have a situation like this is:
We have several subfolders on the file system level of the project dir and add them to XCode into separate groups.
This works well. For actually building, we try to avoid Files with the same Name in one target. Icon.png and iTunesArtwork are only added once in every target.
It just proved to be a Maintainability Nightmare

Comment: What if you want to have a group called GenericIcons and another group called ClientSpecificIcons and they contain info like this? GenericIcons has mail.png, star.png, bill.png; and ClientSpecificIcons has mail.png and star.png only. I want to use mail.png and star.png from ClientSpecificIcons and only bill.png from GenericIcons. How do I do that? In other words, how do I make the ClientSpecificIcons group have priority over the GenericIcons group?

Comment: Why would you want that? just set up your targets correctly so that only the necessary objects are included. Everything else sounds dangerous to me.